# Output Checked Items in Javascript Using Confirm()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output the selected checked items from my list (I am using checkboxes) on the alert message on my page. Essentially, when the user hits the Delete button, I want a confirmation box to pop up and show the user which items they have selected to confirm it's correct (in this case, Serial Numbers). By default, all checkboxes are false (unchecked). If a checkbox is checked, the checkbox variable = true. Below is the function I wrote to do this:

```
function validateDeleteForm() {
        var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("pickSerial");
        var okay=false;
        
        for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(checkboxs[i].checked)
            {
                okay=true;
            }
        }
        if(okay)
            {
                if (confirm("Do you want to delete the selected Serial Number(s) from casting? Hit OK to Delete or CANCEL to re-select: " + this.checkboxs ) == true) { // this will delete selected serial numbers and display
                    return true;
                }
                //return true;
                else { // this will cancel the delete dialogue and allow user to re-select
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
        else {
            alert("You have at least one line to be checked");
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I have tried referencing the checked items doing checkboxs[i].value, this.checkboxs[i], and calling the checkboxs variable but they all show as undefined.

[Here is a screenshot of the output currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icee6.png)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using querySelectorAll you can right away select all of the checked elements. There is no need to have to loop to find the check ones with this. You can then turn the html collection into an array to get all of the values. You can then use that array to display the info to the use.

```js
const cbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="pickSerial"]:checked'));
const serials = cbs.map(function (cb) { return cb.value; });
if (serials.length) {
  console.log(serials.join(",");
}
```

Comment: so you're saying I should create two new variables and instead of using a for loop to iterate through each element, just store them all into the array cbs and use that to grab the checked elements in my Confirm() function?

Comment: thank you for the help,  your answer helped me getting this working how I wanted. You're the best :D

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your solution, you can create an array to track checked items and then when printing, just use that array

Sample

```
const checked = [];
// When you are setting okay = true, push that value in checked
checked.push(checkboxs[i].value)

// Now when you are showing it in confirm box just join the array
confirm('text ' + checked.join(', '))
```

Hope that helps.